# JQuery Adding portrait/landscape class to multiple background images

Tags: html, jquery

I'd like to add portrait or landscape classes to multiple background images divs depending on their orientations in a slider.
ie
`<div class="landscape"` and/or `<div class="potrait"`

```
var img = new Image;
img.src = $('#imgFit').attr("data-bg");
var bgImgWidth = img.width;
var bgImgHeight = img.height;
if (bgImgWidth > bgImgHeight) {
    $('.bg').addClass('landscape');
}
else {
    $('.bg').addClass('portrait');
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="imgFit" class="bg" data-bg="https://www.fillmurray.com/200/300" style="background-image: url('https://www.fillmurray.com/200/300');"></div>
<div id="imgFit" class="bg" data-bg="https://www.fillmurray.com/640/360" style="background-image: url('https://www.fillmurray.com/640/360');"></div>
```

My issue is that it's adding the same class to all divs according to the first one's orientation. Is there any possible way to get different classes ie "portrait" or "landscape" for each of the divs.

Many thanks

Comment: Add your CSS as well where `portrait` and `landscape` have been defined.

Comment: You need a `.each()` loop and within that loop manage individual instances.  `'$('.bg').each(function(){  var img = new Image; img.src = $(this).attr("data-bg")....`